# AMD without depending on AMD framework

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, requirejs, amd

I'm teaching myself to use [require.js](http://require.js) and I'm wondering if it's possible to define all of my modules such that they are unaware of any module/AMD framework.  I'm accustomed to dependency injection in .NET using Unity, where I define all my registrations in a single class, i.e.:

```
_container.RegisterType<IMyType, MyType>();
_container.RegisterType<IMyOtherType, MyOtherType>();
```

From the examples I've seen of require.js, a module is defined inline with its registration:

```
define('myModule', ['myDependency'], function(myDependency) {
    ...
});
```

In this example, the implementation of `myModule` is essentially registering itself as `myModule`.  I'd like the implementation to not depend on require.js or any other module framework.  For example, the implementation of `myModule` might just look like this:

```
function myModuleImplementation(myDependency) {
    ...
}
```

and in a separate file, I would register this function as `myModule`:

```
define('myModule', ['myDependency'], myModuleImplementation);
```

Is this pattern possible using require.js?

Comment: Without an additional abstraction layer I do not see a simple way. What technology do you use on the server side? C#?